# build excel file and send it to client jax-rs java

Tags: java, jax-rs

Hi I am trying to dynamically build excel data from an endpoint and return it back to my client using java  JAX-RS

So right now I have a simple button that calls my function that does a get to this java endpoint and I am trying to use StringBuilder to build up the data I want to return put that to a CSV XLS or whatever and return it to the client.

```
@GET  
    @Path("/excelregisterbycountry")  
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)  
    public Response excelRegister(
            @QueryParam("ModelNumber") String modelNbr,
            @DefaultValue("US") @QueryParam("Country") String country) { 

        String myQuery = "";


        try {
            database = new EstateDatabaseManager(azureHost, azureDB);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            connectionFailed = true;
            slrLog.write(DB_CONNECT_FAIL + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (!connectionFailed) {


                 myQuery = "SELECT distinct spr.country_code, spr.store_nbr, spr.register_nbr, spr.os_version_nbr, sco.adkversion, sco.termType, RTRIM(spr.bios_version_nbr), RTRIM(rt.model_nbr), st.store_type_desc, psi.os_level_id, psi.gsa_level_id, RTRIM(psi.self_checkout_type_cd), psi.si_level, psi.pf_level " +
                          "FROM str_pos_register2 spr " +
                          "JOIN register_type rt " +
                          "ON rt.register_type_cd = spr.register_type_cd " +
                          "join pos_store_info3 psi " +
                          "ON psi.country_code = spr.country_code " +
                          "AND psi.store_nbr = spr.store_nbr " +
                          "join store_type as st " +
                          "on psi.store_type_cd = st.store_type_cd " +
                          "Left join sco.daily sco " +
                          "on spr.register_nbr = sco.registernbr and  spr.country_code = sco.countryCode and spr.store_nbr = sco.storeNbr and cast(spr.last_check_ts as date) = sco.reportDate " +
                          "WHERE spr.country_code <> '??' " +
                          "AND psi.store_status_code = 0 " +
                          "AND rt.model_nbr = ? " +
                          "AND spr.country_code = ? " +
                          "AND spr.last_check_ts > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -7) "+
                          "ORDER BY spr.store_nbr";
            }

            try {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    sb.append("Country Code");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Store Number");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Register NUmber");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("OS Version");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("ADK Version");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Term Type");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Bios Version");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Model Number");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Store Type");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("OS Level ID");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("GSA Level ID");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("Self Checkout Ind");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("siLevel");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("pfLevel");
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("\n");
                trouxInfoScoRegisterObject[] dataObject = null;
                List<trouxInfoScoRegisterObject> dataStore = new ArrayList<trouxInfoScoRegisterObject>();
                trouxInfoScoRegisterObject trouxRegister = null;
                PackageType<trouxInfoScoRegisterObject> t = new PackageType<>();

                database.prepareSQL(myQuery);
                database.addParameter(modelNbr, EstateDatabaseManager.TYPE_STRING);
                database.addParameter(country, EstateDatabaseManager.TYPE_STRING);
                database.query();
                while (database.nextRow()) {
                    trouxRegister = new trouxInfoScoRegisterObject();
                    String countryCode = database.getColumn(1);
                    Integer storeNumber = database.getColumnInt(2);
                    Integer registerNumber = database.getColumnInt(3);
                    String osVersionNbr = database.getColumn(4);
                    String adkVersion = database.getColumn(5);
                    String termType = database.getColumn(6);
                    String biosVersionNbr = database.getColumn(7);
                    String ModelNumber = database.getColumn(8);
                    String storeType = database.getColumn(9);
                    String osLevelId = database.getColumn(10);
                    String gsaLevelId = database.getColumn(11);
                    String selfCheckoutInd = database.getColumn(12);
                    String siLevel = database.getColumn(13);
                    String pfLevel = database.getColumn(14);

                    sb.append(countryCode);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(storeNumber);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(registerNumber);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(osVersionNbr);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(adkVersion);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(termType);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(biosVersionNbr);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(ModelNumber);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(storeType);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(osLevelId);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(gsaLevelId);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(selfCheckoutInd);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(siLevel);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append(pfLevel);
                    sb.append(",");
                    sb.append("\n");


                }

                FileWriter file = new FileWriter("test.csv");
                file.append(sb.toString());
                ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(file);
                rb.header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=rest-test.xlsx");
                return rb.build();


            }catch(Exception e) {
                slrLog.write(NEXT_ROW_ERR + e.getMessage());
                }
```

I am trying to build this all up then just return it back to the client I think my problem is I don't need FileWriter that is looking to write the StringBuilder a file which I do not want I just wanna return what the StringBuilder builds into a CSV format. everything runs smoothly until the return it says source not found because of course, I do not have a test.csv anywhere. I tried just doing `response.ok(sb.tostring())` but it just returns my data in plain text back to the client, not a CSV or excel file. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use `application/octet-stream` just because it is a file download. Use the correct mime type based on what the data actually is. If it is a CSV file, then use `text/csv` as that is the standard<sup>1</sup>

   ```
   @Produces("text/csv")
   ```
2. For the entity, simply return the String. That's all you need to do. No need for a `File` or `FileWriter` or any sort of intermediate storage.

   ```
   return Response.ok(sb.toString())
           .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
                   "attachment;filename=test.csv")
           .build();
   ```

And that's it. Pretty simple.

Note that CSV and Excel files are not the same thing. A CSV file is text file, while Excel files are binary files. Your data is CSV data, so I am not sure why you are labeling the file name as a `.xls` file. It should be `.csv`

---

<sub>1. [Incomplete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)</sub>

Comment: hey thank you for your response I actually had this once before and it still didn't work it doesn't download a file I get a raw response of the data I expect but no test.csv file ever downloads. I am ok with this just being a csv file I am just not sure why it doesn't work. I did everything you said and still no file downloads but the data coming back works fine.

Comment: What client are u using? You should just type the URL in the browser URL bar. It worked fine for me when I tested it before posting this answer.

Comment: this is angularjs client but I am just using a httpget I figured java would return the file no matter what kind of client it is. I don't use angularjs that much so I am not sure if that is what is going on

Comment: It's an angular issue. Try to type it in the URL bar. See for yourself.

Comment: haha you are right it is an angular issue works just find typing in the full url. ..... I am kinda mad I spent this much time on it now I have to figure out why angular js doesn't return it and let the client do the download still giving you the credit because you are exactly right man thanks.

Comment: If you just put the URL to the file in an `<a href>` and someone clicks it, it should download

Comment: I did I just did window.location.href = url on my function and it downloads just fine kind of stupid angularjs does that. but always a work around thanks again this is very helpful